# SQL multiple UNNEST in single select list

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest, set-returning-functions

I was implementing a Query system. I implemented unnest function.
Now user was asking about using multiple unnest in a single select statement.
I was using PostgreSQL as kind of guideline since most users was using it before our query system.

PostgreSQL has such strange behavior:

```
postgres=# select unnest(array[1,2]), unnest(array[1,2]);
 unnest | unnest
--------+--------
      1 |      1
      2 |      2
(2 rows)

postgres=# select unnest(array[1,2]), unnest(array[1,2,3]);
 unnest | unnest
--------+--------
      1 |      1
      2 |      2
      1 |      3
      2 |      1
      1 |      2
      2 |      3
(6 rows)
```

My implementation was always generate as Cartesian product. 
I'm wondering, what's the correct logic behind this? Is PostgreSQL doing right thing or just a bug? I didn't find clear description in ANSI document or PostgreSQL document.

Comment: Related answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782374/many-to-many-relation-in-operator-and-possibility-of-improper-results/21784881#21784881) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450). The last one with details about `LATERAL` and the upcoming `WITH ORDINALITY` in 9.4.

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't about unnest as such, but about PostgreSQL's very weird handling of multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list. Set-returning functions in `SELECT` aren't part of the ANSI SQL standard.

You will find behaviour much saner with `LATERAL` queries, which should be preferred over using a a set-returning function in `FROM` as much as possible:

```
select a, b FROM unnest(array[1,2]) a, LATERAL unnest(array[1,2,3]) b;
```

e.g.

```
regress=> select a, b FROM unnest(array[1,2]) a, LATERAL unnest(array[1,2,3]) b;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 1
 1 | 2
 1 | 3
 2 | 1
 2 | 2
 2 | 3
(6 rows)
```

The only time I still use multiple set-returning functions in `SELECT` is when I want to pair up values from functions that both return the same number of rows. The need for that will go away in 9.4, with multi-argument `unnest` and with support for `WITH ORDINALITY`.

Comment: but in the FROM clause they can't have aggregates `unnest(array_agg(id))`

Comment: Note that this weird behaviour may change in a future PostgreSQL version. Do not rely on it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Right, you need to handle that in a subquery. (Please post a new question and put a link to it in the comments here.)

Comment: Note that the **weird behavior ended with Postgres 10** (just like Craig predicted). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860