# postgresql, select multiple json_array_elements works so werid

Tags: json, postgresql, select

I want use json_array_elements to expands json array. But it works so werid. Pls see below.

> select json_array_elements('[1, 2]') as a, json_array_elements('[2, 3, 4]') as b;

```
a | b
---+---
1 | 2
2 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 4
```

(6 rows)

> select json_array_elements('[1, 2]') as a, json_array_elements('[2, 3]') as b;

```
a | b
---+---
1 | 2
2 | 3
```

(2 rows)

It's seems when the length of the arrays are equal, something goes wrong.
Can anyone tell me, why is like this.

Comment: My postgresql's version is 9.4.4. I installed 9.6.2 and run the test sql, nothing changed.

Comment: [SQL multiple UNNEST in single select list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23003601/1995738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL repeats each list until both happen to be at the end simultaneously.

In other words, the length of the result list is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the length of the input lists.

This behaviour is indeed weird, and will be changed in PostgreSQL v10:

```
select json_array_elements('[1, 2]') as a, json_array_elements('[2, 3, 4]') as b;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
 2 | 3
   | 4
(3 rows)
```

From the [commit message](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=69f4b9c85f168ae006929eec44fc44d569e846b9):

> While moving SRF evaluation to ProjectSet would allow to retain the old
>   "least common multiple" behavior when multiple SRFs are present in one
>   targetlist (i.e.  continue returning rows until all SRFs are at the end of
>   their input at the same time), we decided to instead only return rows till
>   all SRFs are exhausted, returning NULL for already exhausted ones.  We
>   deemed the previous behavior to be too confusing, unexpected and actually
>   not particularly useful.

Comment: Oh, that why. thanks very much. And when PostgreSQL add this change, will it in PostgreSQL 10?

Comment: Yes. I have added details concerning that to the answer.